# Why is this norm not always equal to $0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $B$ is a Banach space, $S$ is a closed linear subspace of $B$. Subspace $S$ defines an equivalence relation $f\sim g$ to mean $f-g\in S$. Let $B/S$ denote the collection of these equivalence classes. Let $\|f\|_{B/S}=\inf(\|g\|_B\mid g\sim f)$.

I'm having trouble showing that $\|f\|_{B/S}$ satisfies $\|f\|_{B/S}=0 \Leftrightarrow f=0$. In particular, if $f\in B/S$, then $f\in S$. Further, $-f\in S$ since $S$ is a linear subspace. So for arbitrary $f\in B/S$, $\|f\|_{B/S}=\inf(\|g\|_B\mid g\sim f)=0$, since $g=0\in B$ and $0-f\in S$. But this contradicts $f=0 \Rightarrow \|f\|_{B/S}=0$.

I am probably missing something silly here, and would greatly appreciate if someone could point that thing out to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write "if $f \in B/S$, then $f \in S$", which is **not** true in general, more precisely, it is true if and only if $f =0$ in $B/S$. 
So in this case, $f=0$ in $B/S$ means that $f$ is equivalent to $0$ and the result follows using your argument (no need to take $-f$).

Comment: Ok I must have misunderstood the set $B/S$. I have $B/S=\{s\in S: s=f-g \text{ for some } f,g\in B\}$. I'm a bit confused by the notion of having a collection of equivalence classes. So each equivalence class is a set? I was thinking of each class corresponding to a single point in S.

Comment: No, that's not what $B/S$ is. $B/S$ is the quotient space defined by $B/S=\{f +S \mid f \in B\}$. So each element of $B/S$ is a collection of functions of $B$ such that their differences always belongs to $S$. Does it make more sense now? Writing $f \in B/S$ is slightly improper, and maybe confusing, one can write $[f]$ to denote the fact that *an element* in $B/S$ is *a collection of elements* in $B/S$.